# Setting multiple cards in CardLayout to False all at once

Tags: java, swing, visible, cardlayout

I understand the concept that with Card Layout for Swing, to switch cards, you can simply call the card you want and set the visibility to either true or false. For example, given four cards named a, b, c, and d, I want a to be displayed but b,c,and d to not be displayed. For now, I have my code set similar to this:

```
a.setVisible(true);
b.setVisible(false);
c.setVisible(false);
d.setVisible(false);
```

Is there anyway that instead of having to call all four cards and set their visibility individually that I can call all at once, set them to false, and then set Card a to true?
For example

```
//some method to set all cards to false
a.setVisible(true);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the concept that with Card Layout for Swing, to switch cards, you can simply call the card you want and set the visibility to either true or false

No, that is not the concept. You never play with the visibility of the panels. The CardLayout does that for you. All you do is use the `show(), next() or previous()` methods.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example.

Comment: camickr is talking about [`CardLayout.show(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29) method; `component.show()` method is deprecated.

Comment: @GregHumiston, read the tutorial, play with the example, then ask follow up questions if there is something you still don't understand. You can also look at Sage's example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you even need such option with `CardLayout`. It has `previous`, `next` and `first` function to traverse the component like flipping a card. [**Check out this demo example to see `CardLayout` in action**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175330/a-back-home-button-java/20175402#20175402). If you still need to have such option for your own reason, why not trying to get the `CardContainer` component list:

```
Component[] comp = cardContainer.getComponents();
comp[0].setVisible(false);
```

Comment: -1, That is not how a CardLayout should be used. The CardLayout manages the visibility for you so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yes, that is why i have put a line `I don't know why do you even need such option` and i was at the middle of editing answer when you were downvoting :) Even after your comment there is still 2 mins to elapse

Comment: Removed the downvote (although I still find your answer very misleading). The OP is trying to understand HOW to use a CardLayout and the code you post suggests an approach that has nothing to do with using a CardLayout properly.

Comment: @camickr, i understand. The problem is that i read his first line `I understand the concept that with Card Layout for Swing, to switch cards, you can simply call the card you want` and then moved to his written `setVisible(boolean)` code. So i got confused whither he did understand or not or what really he wants ! :).